# How to retrieve a php information inide a javascrip

Tags: javascript, php

Inside my `product.php` code, I have a loop

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0, $n = \count($languages); $i < $n; $i++) {
?>
  <div class="row" id="seoDefaultTitleH<?php echo $languages[$i]['id']; ?>">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="form-group row" data-index="<?php echo $languages[$i]['id']; ?>">
        <label for="<?php echo $SEO->getDef('text_seo_defaut_language_title_h1'); ?>" class="col-5 col-form-label"><?php echo $SEO->getDef('text_seo_defaut_language_title_h1'); ?></label>
        <div class="col-md-7 input-group" id="seo_default_title_h<?php echo $languages[$i]['id']; ?>">
          <?php echo '&nbsp;' . HTML::inputField('seo_defaut_language_title_h1_[' . $languages[$i]['id'] . ']', ($seo_defaut_language_title[$languages[$i]['id']] ?? SeoAdmin::getSeoTitleH1($seo->seo_id, $languages[$i]['id'])), 'maxlength="70" size="77" id="seo_default_title_h_' . $languages[$i]['id'] . '"', false); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Inside my `script.php` I have these elements

As you inside my js, I need to take a PHP function to retrieve the good language. But I do not find How to do that allowing the PHP function to be operational.

```
let language_name = '{$Language->getLanguagesName(' + language_id + ')}';
```

all the code

```
$Language = Registry::get('Language');

$content = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm submit-button" data-index="0">';
$content .= '<i class="bi-chat-square-dots" title="' . $this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title') . '"></i>';
$content .= '</button>';

$output = <<<EOD
<script defer>
$('[id^="seo_default_title_h"]').each(function(index) {
  let button = '{$content}';
  let newButton = $(button).attr('data-index', index);
  let inputId = $(this).attr('id'); 
  let regex = /(\d+)/g; 
  let idSeoDefaultTitleH = regex.exec(inputId)[0];
 
  // Here is the problem to retrieve language_id
  let language_id = parseInt(idSeoDefaultTitleH); // OK
  let language_name = '{$Language->getLanguagesName(' + language_id + ')}'; // NOT OK

  let questionResponse = '{$question_title}' + ' ' + '{$store_name}' + ' : traduction ' +  language_name 
  
  newButton.click(function() {
    let message = questionResponse;

    $.post("{$url}", {message: message}, function(data) {
      $("#output-input").val(data);
      $("#seo_default_title_h_" + idSeoDefaultTitleH).val(data); 
    });
  });

  $(this).append(newButton); 
});
</script>
EOD;

return $output;
```

Comment: Why not just send the language_id to the script you are calling with ajax and use the PHP function there, and return it's response?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I am not the best guy with js, let me know more with an example. tk